# How to render with graphic card in Cinema4D?

Tags: motion-graphics, cinema4d, render

I have a powerful graphics card so would like to use it for rendering, rather than my cpu. How can I do this in Cinema4D

Answer (score 0):

Cinema 4D is constrained to CPU rendering. You'll need to look at other products if you want to use GPU.